# python async that doesn't always await

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have a python async function:

```
async def exampleAsync(self,check):
   # normal blocking code

   if check:
      x = await asynch_func()
      # some other code
```

If i run `obj.exampleAsync(False)` and I know this function isn't going to ever call await. Is it wrong to still call this function like:

```
   await obj.exampleAsync(False)
```

I guess it's the right thing to do since I don't know in the code if this function will await or not.

I guess my question is do async function always have to await()?

Answer (score 0):

Here is `await` for new programmers: "`await` pause the code running here until this call is finished, and while you pause here you can run async code elsewhere" So yes.

I think you have misunderstood await. Await is not a call. And yes, passing false will make this just like a non asynchronous program. You never give the eventloop a change to do something else.